# Updating graph with new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Fairly new to d3.js, so hoping there's something obvious that I'm missing. Have been looking at this code over and over again, not sure where it's going wrong.

I have a bargraph, which displays 28 bars. I'm trying to:

1. Replicate this [tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html), where new data is added to graph, and oldest data is removed.
2. Instead of using shift to remove data, I'd like to push to the graph/array, but only display the last 28 numbers. I'd like to use the whole array for another display. This said, I can't get the above to work.

This is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSYQW/) to the troublesome code.

I have a graph located within a group (with a unique ID, #kI1data, plan on having multiple graphs later). When that group is clicked, a value from the data array is shifted, and another pushed. The graph is then redrawn. I believe it's this redraw function that is causing an issue; it removes rectangles, but doesn't add any new ones after the first click.

```
graphGroup.append("g")
    .attr("id", "kInv1")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "invBack")
    .attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", kI1width).attr("height", kI1height)
    .attr("fill", "grey")
    .on("click", dataChange); // Add/remove data, and update graph  

function dataChange() {

    kInvd1.shift();
    kInvd1.push(30); // 30 a placeholder number
    updateGraph();  

};

function updateGraph() {

    // Select the group containing the rectangles that need updating
    // (to avoid selecting other rectangles within the svg)
    var kI3dataSelect = d3.select("#kI1data").selectAll("rect").data(kInvd1, function(d) { return d; });    

    // Enter new data
    kI3dataSelect.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 1 + ((i+1) * ((kI1width)/28)); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return ykI1(d); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return (kI1height) - ykI1(d); })
        .attr("width", (kI1width)/28)
        .attr("fill", "black");

    // Update positions (shift one bar left)
    kI3dataSelect
        .transition().duration(100)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 1 + (i * ((kI1width)/28)); });

    kI3dataSelect.exit()
        .transition().duration(100)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 1 + ((i-1) * ((kI1width)/28)); })
        .remove();

};
```

For now I'm just trying to get the newly added data to display, whilst the oldest data is removed. Once that's done, if there are any pointers on how to display just the last 28 numbers in the array, it'd be very much appreciated!

The jsFiddle shows how a new bar is added on the first click, but subsequent clicks only translate and remove data, whilst new bars are not added.

Comment: You haven't bound the new data in your updateGraph function, so add .data(kInvd1) after enter().  I also think you'll want to change the .attr("x" ... line so that you're just adding 1 to i.  For displaying just a the last 28 entries of an array you could either use the d3 filter function or you could use javascript slice to pre-process your data.

Comment: Adding .data(kInvd1) after enter() gives an error. I can update var `kI3dataSelect = d3.select("#kI1data").selectAll("rect").data(kInvd1, function(d) { return d; });` to refer to 'kInvd1'. Any help with filter? If I remove the kInvd1.shift(); to get an ever-expanding array, I was hoping `d3.select("#kI1data").selectAll("rect").data(kInvd1).filter(function(d, i ) { return i >= (kInvd1.length - 28) });` would work once the array is larger than 28 entries. enter() doesn't like it, however. Reading around the subject suggests something to do with the index, but I'm struggling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your `dataChange` function to the following gets you new insertions and limits the over all array to 28 elements.

```
function dataChange() {
  if (kInvd1.length >= 28) kInvd1.shift()
  kInvd1.push(Math.random() * 60); // 30 a placeholder number
  updateGraph();
};
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSYQW/3/) with your change. On the first click, an element (last blue rectangle) is unexpectedly removed, and once all entries in array are from random function (black), the transition behaviour as they are removed is different to the blue rectangle transition.